# Taxes/Investing in Gold and Silver

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, precious-metals

I am a 19 year old college student and a US resident. I recently got a job and am making $15/hr (which may increase) ~15 hrs per week. I live with my parents and have no expenses. I want to save/invest money for 2-4 years before I move out. I have always wanted to invest in precious metals (gold/silver) as a hedge against inflation. I have two semi-related questions:

1. Would you recommend that I invest in physical gold/silver vs an ETF? The way I see it is that when buying myself from a dealer I pay 5+% over spot price, and would also be selling below spot price, while with an ETF the purchasing cost is much less (IAU/iShares gold trust with $15.67 billion in capital has an expense ratio of .25%). Given this information, why would anyone buy physical gold/silver?
2. Regarding taxes, the research I did has told me that in the U.S gold/silver has a unique collectibles tax rate of 28% no matter what, while my short term (<1 year) capital gains rate based on the chart below would be 10% or maybe 12% depending on the hours I worked.
   [image]

   So, if I were to invest in gold/silver, would it make sense for me to sell the holdings before a year, and then rebuy them so that I could take advantage of the lower short term rate compared to the collectibles tax rate? Is that allowed?

Comment: This is unrelated to how to buy gold, but if your goal is to save money then a savings account would likely be a lot better. Yes you'll have losses due to inflation but your returns are pretty much guaranteed. With physical gold you have high transaction costs, potential tax complications, and high volatility – you might very well lose half of the value. Gold isn't a good investment, but depending on your beliefs it might be a good hedge against catastrophic financial events such as hyperinflation.

Comment: @amon I agree with what you mentioned regarding savings accounts (and I still plan to keep some money in savings/checking accounts). I am mainly interested in buying gold/silver to hedge against hyperinflation or a currency collapse.

Comment: Two comments: 1) short-term gains on gold are taxed as ordinary income, and 2) it's not widely accepted that gold is a great inflation hedge.

Comment: If you're interested in the hedge against currency collapse I would think that an ETF isn't what you're looking for since you'd have to sell and then cash out to USD. you may also have to wait for transfers/wires and funds to settle. So if that's your only goal you're clearly going to have to go with physical gold.

Comment: Note that long-term capital gains (greater than a year) is almost at a lower tax rate than short-term gains, with exception perhaps only due to the special treatment of "collectibles". https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/taxes/capital-gains-tax-rates/ So if you hold stocks, there would be no need to sell until you want the money. Note that investments can and do lose money. If you are buying at a high and selling at a low for IAU, looking at high/low within 12 months across the last 5 years, you could have lost up to 40-50% of what you put in. Be sure to weight the risk of loss against the gain.

Comment: @xyious I appreciate your comment as I hadn't really though of that.

Answer (score 1):

Physical gold should be held in a commercial gold vault but major bullion dealers arrange the gold storage.

Investors in any income tax bracket lower than 28% should consider selling gold before the one-year time period for becoming a long-term asset in the U.S. Then the gold can be re-bought. But selling and re-buying works best with an ETF. Also, there are internet-based financial services companies that buy, sell, and vault gold for customers who have accounts. And there is a Canadian ETF that has a method of avoiding the U.S. collectibles tax rate on gold.